# id to NSString return null when passing to another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have this code below that send the row to my another class:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MeInfos" sender:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)indexPath.row]];

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    MeInfosViewController *viewController = [[MeInfosViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.paramethersToLoad = (NSString*)sender;
    NSLog(@"Will receive -> %@",sender);
}
```

In my another class (MeInfoViewController) I have:

**.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *paramethersToLoad;
```

**.m**

```
@synthesize paramethersToLoad;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"What comes? -> %@",paramethersToLoad);
}
```

This code has a little problem, in console I receive the following messages:

```
Will receive -> 4
What comes? -> (null)
```

Why this is happening and what the best way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view controller you're creating in prepareForSegue: isn't the instance that the segue will actually load. The view controller that actually gets displayed is created by the iOS runtime, and is passed to you as a property in the segue.

What you want is:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    MeInfosViewController *viewController = (MeInfosViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    viewController.paramethersToLoad = (NSString *)sender;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your prepareForSegue should look like this :

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MeInfos"]) {
         // Get reference to the destination view controller
          MeInfosViewController *viewController = [segue destinationViewController]; 

           viewController.paramethersToLoad = (NSString*)sender;
     }
}
```